# Eclipse: Internationlise tooltip text for menu

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

In eclipse I'm trying to internationlize some strings and stuck on trying to find tooltip text which needs to be translated. In the following image I'm focusing on the little triangle that when hovered over displays the text "View Menu". It's this text that I'm looking to find in the code but can't find it anywhere, so I'm assuming it's part of the eclipse platform somewhere, but I haven't a clue where.

It's strange because the minimize and maximize hover text I can locate in an SWT plugin folder but again, "View Menu" is nowhere.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at [Eclipse Babel](https://www.eclipse.org/babel/) which provides standard translations of core Eclipse modules for many languages?

Comment: That was actually mentioned to me a couple of weeks ago but never followed it up. I'll check it out thanks!

Comment: I guess it is [here](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt/src/org/eclipse/e4/ui/internal/workbench/renderers/swt/messages.properties?id=e78b54bbe5decb31d320597859fa04560a2ed496#n22).

Comment: Thanks but that is in version E4. I have to work with E3 here.